# Cross platform way to include system header files, when there is an identically named file in path?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, macros

I am trying to get [Bloomberg's BDE library](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde) to compile in Visual Studio 2015. Because they re-implement the standard libraries typically provided by the compiler, there are header files that have names that exactly match the standard library names, such as `stddef.h`. They optionally allow you to turn off the overriding of the standard library, and to facilitate this, the files they re-implemented will optionally just include the original compiler supplied version such as `stddef.h`. They do this include through macros such as the following:

```
#   if defined(BSLS_COMPILERFEATURES_SUPPORT_INCLUDE_NEXT)
#     include_next <stddef.h>
#   else
#     include BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(stddef.h)
#   endif
```

[Source](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/4768084d489cb1e22a4f2ca53cb6dc3037fc2faf/groups/bsl/bsl%2Bstdhdrs/stddef.h)

Where `BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER` expands to something like this:

```
#if defined(BSLS_PLATFORM_CMP_SUN) // Sun Compiler
#   define BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(filename) <../include/filename>

#elif defined(BSLS_PLATFORM_CMP_CLANG) || defined(BSLS_PLATFORM_CMP_GNU)
  // Clang and GCC use 'include_next'

#elif defined(BSLS_PLATFORM_CMP_HP) // HP Compiler
#   define BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(filename) <../include_std/filename>

#else
  // Most other compilers
#   define BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(filename) <../include/filename>

#endif
```

[Source](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/4768084d489cb1e22a4f2ca53cb6dc3037fc2faf/groups/bsl/bsl%2Bstdhdrs/bsl_stdhdrs_incpaths.h)

The issue is that Visual Studio 2015 [introduces some refactoring](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx) that moves **some** of the C Standard Library header files to a path like this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt`. This obviously means that  `<../include/filename>` will no longer find the moved files. The issue is that all files have not moved. For example, `iso646.h` is still in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include` and will be picked up by the include.

**So here's my question in a nutshell**: Is there a way I can continue to support the `BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER` macro being used, while behind the scenes figuring out whether the import should be from `../ucrt/` or `../include`, based on the file name? I know I could create two separate macros, but I'd rather keep the interface the same if possible.

Comment: "they re-implement the standard libraries typically provided by the compiler" what a stupid way to implement a library.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, the BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER()-like macros would continue to work, while behind the scenes there is a mechanism to override some them based on filename to point at a different directory. At first it seems impossible because the argument to the macros is a filename and may contain "." or "/". But with enough macro-foolery I think it can still be done without changing the build scripts or the filesystem.

BTW, I'm not sure what this says about the C preprocessor, but here goes...

The idea is to construct a series of macros that would be inserted into bsl_stdhdrs_incpaths.h in a MSVC 2015 specific block. There are several of these macros that do basically the same thing, so I have factored the solution so that each user macro like BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER is implemented in terms of a common macro FINDER. The implementation macros have short names for readability, they should get some sort of prefix.

*Caveat: these examples have only been tested on GCC 4.8.4 and unstable, clang-3.5, and MSVC 2015.*

**Simple Idea**

The first clue is that even if the argument to `BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(stddef.h)` contains odd characters, it is not a single token. It is the list {'stddef', '.', 'h'}.

So we could #define stddef to ../include/stddef and it would work because the '.' and 'h' get appended after expansion! But better, we can use ## to paste the first token into macro with a unique name, say `SELECTOR_stddef`. This can then be #defined with a unique path based on each filename:

```
#define ANGLES(f) <f>
#define BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(file) ANGLES(SELECTOR_##file)

/* each can now have a different prefix */
#define SELECTOR_stddef ../ucrt/stddef
#define SELECTOR_stdarg ../include/stdarg

/* later on, down in the user code... */
#include BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(stddef.h) /* #include <../ucrt/stddef.h> */
#include BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(stdarg.h) /* #include <../include/stddef.h> */
```

So this is working great! The only problem is that every single file that is called must have a selector. If not, it will try to include some stupid filename that looks like `#include <SELECTOR_stdio.h>` and it won't work that well. Some maintenance programmer will probably come around and "fix" it by adding a bunch of symlinks to SELECTOR_stdio.h in the /usr/include directory and it will just end badly for everyone.

What would be *really* nice is if there could be a default for most files. Most appear to have been shuffled into .../ucrt and only compiler specific ones are left in .../include. So it would be nice to just override the ones we want. But even in this first form, it may work just fine. It has the advantage of simplicity.

*A bunch of SO questions that helped with this:*

- [Can macros be overloaded by number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683146/can-macros-be-overloaded-by-number-of-arguments)
- [Overloading Macro on Number of Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments)
- [MSVC doesn't expand __VA_ARGS__ correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly)
- [Optional Parameters with C++ Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046889/optional-parameters-with-c-macros)
- [C preprocessor macro specialisation based on an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632219/c-preprocessor-macro-specialisation-based-on-an-argument)
- [Variadic macro trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365440/variadic-macro-trick)
- [Is it possible to iterate over arguments in variadic macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros)

**A More Complete Solution**

```
/* presumably within an #if MSVC 2015 conditional in bsl_stdhdrs_incpaths.h */

#define DELIMITER(a) a

/* same as DELIMITER, but named to distinguish the MSVC __VA_ARGS__ bug */
/* workaround is fine to leave in place for standard compilers */
#define MSVCFIXER(a) a

/* add the angle brackets and re-attach the "rest" tokens */
#define FORMATER(x1, x2, pre, rest, ...) <DELIMITER(pre)rest>

/* if __VA_ARGS__ only has one argument, shift so that pre is the default
 * otherwise if __VA_ARGS__ has two, pre is the override */
#define SHIFTER(pre, rest, def, ...) MSVCFIXER(FORMATER(__VA_ARGS__, pre, rest, def))

/* expand the commas */
#define EXPANDER(...) MSVCFIXER(SHIFTER(__VA_ARGS__))

/* main implementation - pass both the selector override and default */
#define FINDER(file, defloc) \
    EXPANDER(HEAD_LOC_OVERRIDE_##file, DELIMITER(defloc)file,,)

/* now implement the top level macros */
#define BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(file) FINDER(file, HEAD_LOC_DEFAULT_PREFIX)

#define BSL_NATIVE_SYS_TIME_HEADER(file) FINDER(file, HEAD_LOC_DEFAULT_PREFIX)

#define BSL_NATIVE_CISO646_HEADER(file) FINDER(file, /tmp/)

/* maybe define a common default prefix, or hard code it like iso646
 * since most files appear to be in ucrt, make this the default
      (file.h) will become <../ucrt/file.h> */

#define HEAD_LOC_DEFAULT_PREFIX ../ucrt/

/* override any other files NOTE: the commas
 *   (stdarg.h) will become <../include/stdarg.h>
 *   (stdint.h) will become <../include/stdint.h> */

#define HEAD_LOC_OVERRIDE_stdarg ../include/stdarg,
#define HEAD_LOC_OVERRIDE_stdint ../include/stdint,

/* and you can even override the name part too, or remove or add the .h
 *   (where.h) will become <../somewhere/when> (note: use two commas)
 *   (sys/*.h) will become <../include/sys/*.h>
 *   (cstdio)  will become <windows.h> */

#define HEAD_LOC_OVERRIDE_where  ../somewhere/when,,
#define HEAD_LOC_OVERRIDE_sys    ../include/sys,
#define HEAD_LOC_OVERRIDE_cstdio windows.h,

/* later on, down in the user code... */

#include BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(stdarg.h)   /* <../include/stdarg.h */
#include BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(stdio.h)    /* <../ucrt/stdio.h */
#include BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(cstdio)     /* <windows.h> */
#include BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(what.h)     /* <../ucrt/what.h> */
#include BSL_NATIVE_C_LIB_HEADER(where.h)    /* <../somewhere/when> */
#include BSL_NATIVE_CISO646_HEADER(iso646.h) /* </tmp/iso646.h> */
```

Comment: huh, why is it highlighting "when" and "where" in the code block?

Comment: FYI - minor edit to the names of the parameters of SHIFT. Originally they were all named "facetiously". When I renamed everything "rest" was the 3rd parameter which doesn't make sense. There is no difference in behavior, but it should clarify which item is in which parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate directory `../VC14-include-compat` that contains dummy include files that redirect to the actual location of each standard include file.

A simpler hack is to patch your VC14 include directory to add the missing files and make them include from the *new* directory explicitly.

Also, why not use the alternative method and include the bsl include files from the `bsl/bsl+bslhdrs` directory instead of the `bsl/bsl+stdhdrs`.  You will need to modify your source files to include for example `<bsl_c_stddef.h>` instead of `<stddef.h>`, but that will make your project more portable.

The BDE library has 1.7 million lines of code, good luck trying to fix any other portability issues!