# C++ macro with argument

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I want to define like this:

```
    #define log(x)          \
    #if (x)                 \
        cout << "\n" << x   \
    #else                   \  
        cout                \
```

Example:

```
    log() << abc 
    ~
    cout << abc
```

and

```
    log(name) << abc
    ~
    cout << "\n" << name << abc
```

It similar the problem in the question in here [C preprocessor macro specialisation based on an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632219/c-preprocessor-macro-specialisation-based-on-an-argument)

I want to use ***define*** because actually, I use ***cout*** for people can easily understand my intent.

I doing the Qt and need log using QLoggingCategory

```
    QLoggingCategory category("MyNameSpace");
```

And when need log, I need to use the syntax

```
    qCDebug(category) << something_need_log
```

Here, ***qCDebug(category)*** like the ***cout*** in my question.

Comment: Sorry, macros don't work this way, and this is not what they're for. This is something that easily done using a very simple template function.

Comment: Why do you *want* to use a macro? They tend to cause more problems than the alternatives. (By which I mean they cause problems and the alternatives usually do not.)

Comment: Macros, old style cast, most implicit conversions, etc. are things that C++ has only because deprecating them just breaks to much code, but they should be avoided in new code.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& log() {
  return std::cout;
}

std::ostream& log(const std::string& x) {
  return std::cout << "\n" << x;
}

int main() {
    log() << "message";  // std::cout << "message";
    log("name: ") << "message"; // cout << "\n" << "name: " << message;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
message
name: message
```

Comment: Thanks @S.M. but I want to use ***define*** because actually, I use ***cout*** for people can easily understand my intent.

I doing the Qt and need log using QLoggingCategory
        
        QLoggingCategory category("MyNameSpace");

And when need log, I need to use the syntax

        qCDebug(LogQuoteButton) << something_need_log

Here, ***qCDebug(LogQuoteButton)*** like the ***cout*** in my question.