# Can I generate a constant array of size n

Tags: c++, build-time

I  want to generate a constant array *power[501]* = {1, p % MODER, p*p % MODER, p*p*p % MODER, ..., p^500 % MODER}, of which p is an constant number.

I know I could generate *p^n % MODER* by using the following code:

```
template<int a, int n> struct pow
{
  static const int value = a * pow<a, n-1>::value % MODER;
};
template<int a> struct pow<a, 0>
{
  static const int value = 1;
};
```

And it does work!

My question is if I could generate the array that I want?

Comment: What is `MODER`? Some constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`BOOST_PP_ENUM`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/enum.html) as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>

#define MODER 10

template<int a, int n> struct pow
{
  static const int value = a * pow<a, n-1>::value % MODER;
};
template<int a> struct pow<a, 0>
{
  static const int value = 1;
};

#define ORDER(count, i, data) pow<data,i>::value

int main() {
  const int p = 3;
  int const a[] = { BOOST_PP_ENUM(10, ORDER, p) };
  std::size_t const n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
  for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i != n ; ++i ) 
    std::cout << a[i] << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
3
9
7
1
3
9
7
1
3
```

See [online demo](http://ideone.com/22Ffe)

The line:

```
int const a[] = { BOOST_PP_ENUM(10, ORDER, p) };
```

expands to this:

```
int const a[] = { pow<p,0>::value, pow<p,1>::value, ...., pow<p,9>::value};
```

Comment: Does this deal with integer overflow? int^500 is going to be a problem I'd think...

Comment: @tmpearce: That is a problem anyway irrespective of whether you use `BOOST_PP_ENUM` or not. It is a problem with `BOOST_PP_ENUM` itself. It is problem with the definition of `pow` class template. If you handle that case, implement `pow` in such a way to handle this. Simple!

Comment: Thanks a lot. But whatif i don't have a boost library, just g++? is there no solution?

Comment: @abcdabcd987: then you've to either implement the functionality of `BOOST_PP_ENUM` yourself, or initialize the array at runtime!

Answer (score 1):

Unless `n` has an upper bound, I would presume that that is impossible. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136686/is-the-c99-preprocessor-turing-complete) out. There are ways to make the preprocessor look like a Turing-complete machine but only if you accept the fact that your code size should increase in the order of `n`, which is not better than placing a precomputed array by hand.

Important Update: You should see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189172/c-templates-turing-complete) too. It seems that not the preprocessor but the template engine is indeed Turing-complete (at least can do recursion). So, now I suspect that the answer is yes.

Comment: It is no C++ solution. It is not C solution either. It is only C99 solution. `P99` is available in C99 only.