# How no support of #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON affects __STDC_IEC_559__ and __STDC__?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, ieee-754, standards-compliance

This simple code (t217.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <float.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main( void )
{
    feclearexcept( FE_ALL_EXCEPT );
    ( void )( FLT_MAX * FLT_MAX );
    if  ( fetestexcept( FE_OVERFLOW ) )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    printf("error: no FE_OVERFLOW is raised\n");
    return 1;
}
```

compiled with `clang` and executed:

```
$ clang t217.c -std=c11 -ffp-model=strict -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lm && ./a.out
t217.c:5:14: warning: pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON is not supported, ignoring pragma [-Wunknown-pragmas]
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
             ^
1 warning generated.
```

leads to:

```
<nothing>
```

while being compiled with `gcc` and executed:

```
$ gcc t217.c -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lm && ./a.out
t217.c:5: warning: ignoring ‘#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS’ [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    5 | #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
      |
```

leads to:

```
error: no FE_OVERFLOW is raised
```

Both `clang` and `gcc`:

- claim conformance to the specifications in the Annex F (`__STDC_IEC_559__` is `1`)
- *may* (see UPD) claim conforming implementation (`__STDC__` is `1` and `__STDC_VERSION__` is `201112`)
- have no support of `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` (diagnostic message is produced / issued)

By the presence of `error: no FE_OVERFLOW is raised` we've seen that some specifications in the Annex F have been violated.

Note: Here is the example from C11 (F.9.1 Global transformations):

```
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
void f(double x)
{
    /* ... */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) x + 1;
    /* ... */
}
```

with comment:

> `x + 1` might raise floating-point exceptions, so cannot be removed.

Question: since no support of `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` may lead to Annex F violation, how such no support affects `__STDC_IEC_559__`? I.e. should such implementation refrain from defining `__STDC_IEC_559__` to `1`?

Extra question: how no support of `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` affects `__STDC__`? I.e. does the C standard allow to define `__STDC__` to `1` to implementations with "not all the features supported"?

Tool versions:

```
$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

UPD. Yes, `__STDC__ is 1` does not mean *conforming implementation*. It means *conforming implementation OR non-conforming implementation which defines `__STDC__` to `1`*.

Comment: Re “claim conforming implementation (`__STDC__` is `1` and `__STDC_VERSION__` is `201112`)”: You are attributing meaning to those things that cannot exist. The standard says **if** an implementation is conforming, **then** it defines `__STDC__` to be 1. It does not say **if** an implementation defines `__STDC__` to be 1, **then** it is claiming conformance. It cannot, because the C standard cannot govern non-conforming implementations at all. Non-conforming implementations can define anything to be anything, and the C standard has no say about it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Since any unexpected behaviors (bugs, defects, etc.) in implementations defining `__STDC__` to `1` automatically make such implementations _non-conforming implementations which define `__STDC__` to `1`_, does it mean that relying on `__STDC__` (in code) is useless (and, hence, `__STDC__` itself is useless)?

Comment: Can't the compiler optimize out that `FLT_MAX * FLT_MAX`?

Comment: It can conform to IEEE754 for the one rounding mode and the 0 exceptions it does support, no? Although they are supposed not to define FE_OVERFLOW in that case... (btw, more recent clang supports the pragma)

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks for the news! Yes, clang 12.0.0 does support `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`.