# What are the examples of non-ISO practices, which are not found by -pedantic?

Tags: c, gcc, iso, standards-compliance, gcc-pedantic

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html :

> Some users try to use `-Wpedantic` to check programs for strict ISO C conformance. They soon find that it does not do quite what they want: it finds some non-ISO practices, but not all—only those for which ISO C *requires* a diagnostic, and some others for which diagnostics have been added.

What are the examples of non-ISO practices, which are not found by `-pedantic`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is fundamentally that it's possible to write C programs containing errors (not just failures to achieve strict conformance) that it is not reasonable to demand a C compiler detect.  At the time the standard was originally written (1989), whole-program analysis was out of the question, and even now, it's expensive.  And one will always be able to gin up constructs like

```
extern _Bool collatz_sequence_does_not_terminate(int);
int foo(int n) {
    int rv;
    if (collatz_sequence_does_not_terminate(n)) {
        return rv;
    }
    return 23;
}
```

where the answer to "does this program have undefined behavior" depends on a mathematical problem whose solution is unknown.

So the manual is trying to warn you, not just that GCC can't detect all possible violations of ISO C conformance, but that *no compiler* can.  It's worded a little too preciously, if I still worked on GCC I might revise it to be clearer.

---

If you want a concrete example of something that makes the program nonconformant, isn't diagnosed *at all*, and is relatively likely to come up in real life, try this on for size:

```
/* a.c */
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t val = 0x0123456789abcdef;

/* b.c */
#include <stdio.h>
extern double val;
int main(void) {
    printf("%g\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Whole-program analysis is required to detect the type mismatch between the two files.  It's not a difficult case; the compiler *could* annotate each global symbol with its type and the linker *could* check all uses of each symbol for consistency with the definition.  But I'm not aware of *any* toolchain, nor any static analysis product, that *will* detect this error for variables.

Comment: Quirk objection: for all `int n` values the Collatz sequence was shown to terminate. :-) So the program is fine.

Answer (score 4):

GCC support other forms of constant expressions that are not required by ISO C.
For example:

```
int main() {
  const int m = 5;
  static int n = m;
  return n;
}
```

This code compiles fine in "pedantic" mode even though `static` variable is initialized with something that is not a constant expressions conforming to ISO C.

Comment: May be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67266324/1778275.

Answer (score 1):

1. The C Preprocessor, 11.1 [Implementation-defined behavior](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior):

> GCC allows the ‘$’ character in identifiers as an extension for most targets. This is true regardless of the std= switch, since this extension cannot conflict with standards-conforming programs. When preprocessing assembler, however, dollars are not identifier characters by default.

UPD. 2. Allowing "plain `complex`":

```
#include <complex.h>
complex x;

$ gcc t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
```

C11, 6.2.5 Types, 11:

> There are three *complex types*, designated as `float _Complex`, `double _Complex`, and `long double _Complex`.

and 7.3.1 Introduction, 4:

> The macro `complex` expands to `_Complex`;

UPD. 3. `__has_attribute`:

```
#if __has_attribute(xxx)
#endif
int x;

$ gcc t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
```

Comment: I don't disagree, but that seems an oddly specific example to justify necro'ing this question.  There is a wide variety of examples that could be drawn from annexes J.1 - J.5.  Although GCC will diagnose some of those, there are many that it will not.  My personal favorite is "A nonempty source file does not end in a new-line character which is not immediately preceded by a backslash character".